# Ssh into multiple servers and merge files into one

Tags: shell-script, ssh, text-processing, merge

I was able to do it with one server with the following code:

```
ssh server001 << EOF
cat /dir/file001.txt >> somefile
EOF
```

With multiple servers, my script is able to ssh into the servers but for some reasons, it cannot find my file00x files and gives me the following error:
`cat: /dir/file00x.txt: No such file or directory` even though the file does exist.

Here is my code:

```
 for i in {10..15}; do
    ssh $i      //for simplicity, theres some text manipulation to get the actual name of the server
    cat /tmp/$i.txt
 done << newfile.txt
```

I have also tried this method (clearly not the right way), but the file is still not found:

```
 for i in {10..15}; do
    ssh $i      
    cat /tmp/$i.txt >> newfile.txt
 done
```

Tried this too but doesn't work either:

```
 for i in {10..15}; do
    ssh $i  << EOF    
    cat /tmp/$i.txt >> newfile.txt
    EOF
 done
```

Comment: Is the `/tmp/$i.txt` file on the local machine or the remote machine?  Is `newfile.txt` on the local machine or the remote machine?

Comment: /tmp/$i.txt is on the remote machine but newfile.txt is on a shared file system that can be accessed by both remote and local machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I understand the question, you need to access `/tmp/$i.txt` on the remote machine, and it doesn't matter where `newfile.txt` is accessed from.

In this case we don't need to worry about HERE documents or being clever, a simple

```
ssh $i cat /tmp/$i.txt >> newfile.txt
```

will run the `cat` on the remote machine, but will append locally.

This can then be looped:

```
for i in {10..15}
do
  ssh $i cat /tmp/$i.txt >> newfile.txt
done
```

If, instead, you wanted the redirection to also occur on the remote machine then we can quote the command:

```
for i in {10..15}
do
  ssh $i "cat /tmp/$i.txt >> newfile.txt"
done
```

Now the `cat $i.txt >> newfile.txt` happens on the remote machine.

In your setup it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Looks like I need to ssh and cat in the same line..weird..

Comment: `ssh host cmd` means "connect to host and run cmd".  If you had it on two lines then it means "create interactive session on host and _when that finishes_ run cmd locally"; something totally different :-)